# How to build two different project in single repository, using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am in a situation, it's been more than two weeks but I could not solve the problem. Sorry for the long description of the question. What I am trying to do is:

I have two different projects, say `A` and `B` and I have to build them using Jenkins. Though they are independent they work together. So I created to different repositories and called them `Repo-A` and `Repo-B` and I was able to build them.

Here is a real problem: Now I want to build them together from single repository. So I created a repository called `Demo` in Bitbucket and now I have both projects `A` and `B` in `Demo` repository.

Now I created a `pom.xml` file in the `Demo` repository so that I can use it as parent POM and each of the projects `A` and `B` have their own `pom.xml`.

#### Project Demo's `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

  <!--<url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
  </modules>

 <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <name>Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

#### Project A's `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.a.batch</groupId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.01-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>A Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
</project>
```

#### Project `B`'s `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.B</groupId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>B Maven Webapp</name>
    <!--url>http://maven.apache.org</url-->
     <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now when I am building using Jenkins the build is successful but Jenkins is not generating any `war` file. It is generating three different `pom` projects instead.

```
[INFO] A Maven Webapp ........................... SUCCESS [  0.351 s]
[INFO] Demo Maven Webapp ............................ SUCCESS [  0.056 s]
[INFO] B Maven Webapp ....................... SUCCESS [  0.075 s]


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.453 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-30T02:59:14+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins_Projects/workspace/A/pom.xml to com.A/A/1.0-SNAPSHOT/A-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins_Projects/workspace/B/pom.xml to com.B/B/1.0-SNAPSHOT/B-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins_Projects/workspace/Demo/pom.xml to Demo.Demo/Parent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I build the projects standalone, the builds are successful and I am getting `.war` files as well.

But when I am building from same repository `Demo` and using parent `pom.xml` I do not see any `.war` files though the build is successful.

How do I solve this problem?

What is the way to build two projects together?

Why am I getting `pom` instead of `.war`?

Why am I getting `Parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom` though this is not a project. it is just a `pom` inside repository.

Please guide me.

Comment: Please choose one indentation size, then stick to it. At the moment you use 2, 4, 6, 8 and you're even mixing them within files. That's not too reader-friendly.

Comment: Which type of Jenkins project is the job you're running to build `Demo`? Can you add the relevant parts of the Jenkins build log regarding the SCM handling?

Comment: Something must be wrong with your Jenkins setup. Maybe it's picking up old files. Maybe it's misconfigured somehow. Your logs are not consistent: Maven is building A then Demo then B, which shows that you're not building the right project: if this was a true multi-module project, Maven would build Demo first, then A / B (or B / A since they don't depend on eachother).

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to use `mvn deploy` and some artifact repository (like Nexus). This should make this project independent from jenkins problems.

Comment: Parent project `Maven Webapp` should be builded first, and this not happens in your log, so please attach correct projects poms and logs.

Answer (score 4):

> *What is the way to build two projects together?*

You did it right by declaring `<modules>` in the [aggregator](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) project `Parent`.

> *Why am I getting `pom` instead of `.war`?*

You're always getting a `*.pom` if you `install` or `deploy` a Maven project. That's how Maven stores the configuration of a project inside `pom.xml` together with the created artifact in its repositories.

The real question is: Why are you getting *just* a `*.pom` for `A` and `B`?

> *Why am I getting `Parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom` though this is not a project. it is just a `pom` inside repository.*

`Parent` actually **is** a Maven project (with packaging type `pom`). So, getting `Parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom` when building it is perfectly well.

Hint: Consider using [`<dependencyManagment>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) in your parent POM.